# INSERT INTO duplicate key value - how to force insert? Postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql

I have the following problem:

I am trying to run following query in postgresql:

```
INSERT INTO table (date, status, val1, val2, val3) values {}".format(args_str)
```

Date and val3 have a unique key constraint. I want to update both values.
I want to do a bulk insert - passing a string of tuples

`args_str` looks as follows (but is longer in reality):

```
"('2021-11-10 22:00:00+00:00',status1, value_val1,value_val2,value_val3),('2021-11-10 22:15:00+00:00',status1, value_val1,value_val2,value_val3)"
```

I now want to be able to insert these updated values to the DB, but the duplicate key value constraint is getting in the way

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "table_date_val3_key"
```

I tried to implement something like `on duplicate key update ...` but I am unsure how to do this.

Comment: When you say you want to force it to go through, that do you mean you want to to do an update to the existing row? If you mean that you want to force there to be duplicates, then you need to remove the uniqueness constraint.

Comment: what do you mean force them , do you want them to be unique or not? if not  drop unique constraint , if yes then don't insert duplicates

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use on conflict here is the syntax :

```
insert into table (date, status, val1, val2, val3) 
values ('2021-11-10 22:00:00+00:00',status1,value_val1,value_val2,value_val3)
on conflict table_date_val3_key
do update set val3 = value_val3 , date = '2021-11-10 22:00:00+00:00'
```

otherwise you have to update the duplicates
and then insert  the rest

Comment: But I want to do a bulk, not val by value, is that possible?

Comment: @aze45sq6d then you have to update the duplicates and then insert the rest in two seperate commands